# reading the rows of gridview in the server code

Tags: asp.net

How to read the rows of gridview in the server code that added from the JAVASCRIPT in asp.net

I am building a drag drop gridview  and everything is working fin, but the problem is,
 I can't read  the rows of gridview in the server code that added from the JAVASCRIPT

this is the html code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $(".drag_drop_grid").sortable({
                        items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                        cursor: 'crosshair',
                        connectWith: '.drag_drop_grid',
                        axis: 'X',
                        dropOnEmpty: true,
                        receive: function (e, ui) {
                            $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                        }
                    });
                    // $("[id*=gvDest] tr:not(tr:first-child)").remove();
                });
```

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDest" runat="server" CssClass="drag_drop_grid GridDest" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" >
    <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="الرقم الوطني" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="الأسم" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and this is the server code

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
    string id = "";
    gvDest.DataBind();
    if (gvDest.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; gvDest.Rows.Count > i; i++)
        {
            id += gvDest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim()+";;";
            //insert Query
            //command.CommandText =
            //"Insert into FamDivTable (W_Id,H_Id,M_Id) select W_Id,H_Id,M_Id from FamMarTable where W_Id='" + gvDest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim() + "' and H_Id='" + FathId.Text.Trim() + "' ";
            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //command.CommandText =
            //"Delete from FamMarTable where W_Id='" + gvDest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim() + "' and H_Id='" + FathId.Text.Trim() + "' ";
            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Label1.Text = id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I can't read the rows of gridview in the server code that added from the JAVASCRIPT
```

Correct. You would have to either:

- Load the data directly inside your codebehind file
- POST the data into your codebehind file and read the POST data there

Personally, I would load the data in the codebehind directly, as it will be the fastest method and doesn't require more round-trips between the server and the client.